# How to share pages/content from a site collection, to subsites?

Tags: publishing

We will have a whole host of subsites under a single site collection. Each 'normal' user will only have access to one of these sites, plus be given access to some resources at the site collection level.

I'd like to allow the content owners to set up a 'welcome' page, or at least define the content somehow, which is then displayed in each of these subsites, but can then be dynamically updated by the content owners i.e not just a static copy.

I had assumed that this would be pretty straightforward - that i could simply 'link' to a page in the parent site collection, but I can't see any way of doing it.
I could just use a page view control, and have it embedded in an iframe, but then it will double up all of the branding an controls of the page.
Reusable content can't be shared with a subsite, and didn't really match my requirements either.

I'm using SharePoint 2010. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: have you looked at the content query web part? Allows you to roll up/down data from site to site.

Comment: Please **tag by feature or topic** and not by version or product. This helps to attract more attention to your question and keep it relevant. See [How do I use tags](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264/) for more. You may also find [our editing guidelines](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115/have-any-tips-for-editing-questions/116#116) useful which I've used to improve your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your requirement is that you have a large number of sites, one per user, and you want to have a way for a content owner to be able to update the default content on all those subsites, while still allowing the users some control over their own sites, including replacing that content.

My first thought is that it sounds as though you are trying to re-create the MySites functionality. Users get a profile page that is shared amongst all the users, and so can be centrally maintained. But in addition they get the ability to have a "content" site that they can then modify as they wish. I assume there is a reason why you are not doing it this way.

On the face of it, it sounds as though reusable content would satisfy your requirement - it should be possible to use it throughout your subsites. But you have to choose whether to update automatically or to allow users to modify it. You can't have both. Perhaps this doesn't satisfy your requirement, if I have understood it correctly, but you might want to revisit this.

You could make all the subsites use the same site template and include rollup web parts to pull in content from your centrally maintained site. Then allow users the option to remove or modify those web parts. You may need to use a stapled custom feature to provision the web parts the way you want them.

Comment: I couldn't see any way of using the built in reusable content functionality where the content is just defined once, and used repeatedly in subsites. It only appeared to be usable at a site level.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this sounds like a time when list-based content, rather than page-based content, makes more sense. As David mentions above, you could then use the CQWP, or my favorite Web Part, the Data View Web Part (DVWP). With DVWPs, if you have the data in lists and can sketch what you want, you can get it onto a page.

Comment: Sounds like that is what I'll have to do - create a custom page with placeholders for the content,and bring in some list based content. I am more used to a content management system where this sort of thing would be simple, and out of the box - it would simply be a link to a text/html object.
Won't be quite as easy for the owner to update the page, they will have to edit each section in the list, then check how it appears on the page - but sounds like the only way to do it.